# Update two tables using one function in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.7

I'm building an app using Laravel 5.7 and Vue.js2. I have two tables: departments and users. A user can be a chief of a department. I made the relationship between the models. I want it so that when I create a new department, the type of the chief will be changed on the user's table to 'chief.'

**DepartmentController**

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'string|required|max:191',
        'bio' => 'string|required',
        'user_id' => 'integer|required|unique:departements'
    ]);

    return Department::create([
        'name' => $request['name'],
        'user_id' => $request['user_id'],
        'bio' => $request['bio']
    ]);
}
```

Comment: is this `User::find($request['user_id'])->update(['type' => 'chief']);` what you want or I got your question wrong? if not, please provide more details

Comment: yes that's it for example i create a department with a chief named john who has the id 5 so the user_id in the departments table will be 5 so i want to change the type of the user who has the id=5 in the users table(john) to chief

Comment: so is it solved? what is the problem now?

Comment: No it's not anyway. Want to change the user type from the department model

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this.

**Controller**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request,[
        'name'=>'string|required|max:191',
        'bio'=>'string|required',
        'user_id'=>'integer|required|unique:departements'
    ]);

    $new_department = Department::create([
        'name'=>$request['name'],
        'user_id'=>$request['user_id'],
        'bio'=>$request['bio']
    ]);

    $get_user = User::where('id', $request['user_id'])->first();
    if($get_user)
    {
         $get_user->type = 'chief';
         $get_user->save();
    }

    return ['message' => 'success'];

}
```

In this code, After saving the New Department I get the UserData in UserModel where id is the `$request['user_id]` then check it if exists.

If exists, I change the type to `'chief'` and save.

Comment: did you add type to fillable property of user model

Comment: Message error: Class 'App\HTTP\Controllers\API\Uder' not found

Comment: It's solved instead of User I made \App\User thank you but it didn't work for the update function

Answer (score 0):

If you have relationship between two models then you can update like this

```
$product = Department::with('relationship_function_name')->find($id);
$product->fields= $request->input_name;
$product->relationship_function_name->field_name = $request->input_name;
$product->update();
```

Hope this helps :)